# Git clone error "fatal: write error: Operation not supported"

Tags: git, ubuntu, clone, hpc

I am trying to install a software by cloning its github repository into our university's HPC server.

I used the git clone

However, I keep on getting these errors:

```
`fatal: write error: Operation not supported
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Can someone help me out? I am fairly new to git and hpc.

I have already tried using the compress option that I saw online, but it didn't work.

Comment: Assuming the repository itself is fine (it can be cloned to other PCs successfully), I would guess that something with the git installation on that server is the problem. Maybe the git version you use is terribly outdated?

Comment: The git version in the HPC server I'm using says 2.34.1. I opened the HPC server using the local terminal, that is correct right?

Comment: Do you clone to an exotic file system? Perhaps some networked file system?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. I am cloning to our university's HPC.

Comment: The question is whether that system (probably not an off-the-shelf PC) uses some exotic file system or you are lacking permissions to write to the target folder.